# Triggering Databricks job from Airflow without starting new cluster

Tags: airflow, databricks

I am using airflow to trigger jobs on databricks. I have many DAGs running databricks jobs and I whish to have to use only one cluster instead of many, since to my understanding this will reduce the costs these task will generate.

Using `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator`there are two ways to run a job on databricks. Either using a running cluster calling it by id

```
'existing_cluster_id' : '1234-567890-word123',
```

or starting a new cluster

```
'new_cluster': {
    'spark_version': '2.1.0-db3-scala2.11',
    'num_workers': 2
  },
```

Now I would like to try to avoid to start a new cluster for each task, however the cluster shuts down during downtime hence it will not be available trough it's id anymore and I will get an error, so the only option in my view is a new cluster.

1) Is there a way to have a cluster being callable by id even when it is down?

2) Do people simply keep the clusters alive?

3) Or am I completely wrong and starting clusters for each task won't generate more costs?

4) Is there something I missed completely?

Comment: Step1- click on cluster and find below details in URL.

    Step 2: Copy ClusterName from URL as define below.
    https://eastus.azuredatabricks.net/? 
   o=WorkSpaceID#/setting/clusters/<ClusterName>/configuration


    notebook_task_params = {
        'existing_cluster_id': "<ClusterName>",
        'notebook_task': {
            'notebook_path': '/Users/username@domain.com/notebookName',
   
        },
  
    }

Comment: I am not bothered by this problem anymore but I still wonder how you would do it. It seems like there are steps missing, also I was working in AWS not azure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I my case i just pass these steps and working fine in azure.Not tried in AWS I'll check and update here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updates based on @YannickSSE's comment response*
I don't use databricks; Can you start a new cluster by the same id as the cluster you may or may not expect is running and have it be a no-op in the case that it is running? Maybe not, or you probably wouldn't be asking this. *Response: no when starting a new cluster you cannot give an id.*

Could you write a python or bash operator which tests for the existence of the cluster? (*Response: This would be a test job submission… not the best approach.*) If it finds it and succeeds the downstream task would trigger your job with the existing cluster id, but if it doesn't another downstream task could use the [`trigger_rule`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules) `all_failed` to do the same task but with a new cluster. Then both those task `DatabricksSubmitRunOperator`s could have one downstream task with the `trigger_rule` `one_success`. (*Response: Or use a branching operator to determine the operator executed.*)

It might not be ideal because I imagine then that your cluster id is changing from time to time causing you to have to keep up. … Is the cluster part of the databricks hook's connection for that operator, and something that can be updated? Maybe you want to specify it in the tasks that need it as `{{ var.value.<identifying>_cluster_id }}` and keep it updated as an airflow variable. (*Response: the cluster id is not in the hook, so the variable or DAG file would have to be updated whenever it changes.*)

Comment: I only have the two options, running it on a running cluster given the id or start a new cluster (I cannot specify it's id). I could od some branching and start a new cluster but I would need to test to see what happens when the cluster is starting and another dag tries to send a job to this cluster. The id is sadly not a part of the hook databricks uses but instead I have to give it as an argument to the databricks operator. However I can create a variable and update this one. If no better answer comes I will do that. Thanks

Comment: @YannickSSE thanks for clarifying which is the case for my speculation. I am thinking that either you need to use a variable OR make a service which Airflow can have an operator check against (as simple as a rest web request, or a DB query like `SELECT cluster_id FROM active_clusters WHERE intended_use = 'This_DAG_id';`) and if it comes back with a value, push it to xcom and use `{{ ti.xcom_pull('taskname_for_getting_which_cluster') }}` as the cluster_id templated string. Not sure how you'd start a cluster without a job and then find out the ID put it in xcom and POST/insert in the service.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Databricks has added an option recently to reuse a job cluster within a job, sharing it between tasks.

https://databricks.com/blog/2022/02/04/saving-time-and-costs-with-cluster-reuse-in-databricks-jobs.html

> Until now, each task had its own cluster to accommodate for the
> different types of workloads. While this flexibility allows for
> fine-grained configuration, it can also introduce a time and cost
> overhead for cluster startup or underutilization during parallel
> tasks.
>
> In order to maintain this flexibility, but further improve
> utilization, we are excited to announce cluster reuse. By sharing job
> clusters over multiple tasks customers can reduce the time a job
> takes, reduce costs by eliminating overhead and increase cluster
> utilization with parallel tasks.

This seems to be available in the new API as well. https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsCreate

> job_clusters Array of objects (JobCluster) <= 100 items
>
> A list of job cluster specifications that can be shared and reused by
> tasks of this job. Libraries cannot be declared in a shared job
> cluster. You must declare dependent libraries in task settings.

In order to fit your use case you could start a new cluster with your job, share it between your tasks, and it will automatically shut down at the end.

I still don't fully understand how we might keep a job cluster hot all the time if we want to have jobs start with no latency. I also don't think it's possible to share these clusters between jobs.

For now this information should provide a decent lead.

Comment: You can use instnace pools to get faster startup of jobs

Comment: An instance pool, especially one with hot nodes, can reduce the startup times. In my case that brought the startup latency from 3 minutes to 1 minute. Unfortunately I had an ideal of less than 20 seconds in mind, which I haven't been able to achieve. I think this is mostly around the installation of libraries on the hot nodes.

Comment: yes, if you need libraries, then you can create a Docker image with them, and preload it to the nodes together with databricks runtime

Answer (score 0):

In fact when you want to execute a notebook via airflow, you have to specify the characterestics of your cluster.

databricks will consider your notebook as a new job and make it on the cluster you created. But when the execution is finished the cluster created will be deleted autormatically.

To verify this: when job are running on airflow ==> go to see logs => It gives you a link => the link forward you to databricks : There you click on View cluster, so you will see the execution on a new created cluster called for example job-1310-run-980

Comment: Also if you want to delete these job cluster you can do this: Store tokens in a .netrc file and use them in curl
Create a .netrc file with machine, login, and password properties:
`
machine abc-d1e2345f-a6b2.cloud.databricks.com
login token
password dapi1234567890ab1cde2f3ab456c7d89efa
`
`
curl --netrc -X POST https://dbc-a1b2345c-d6e7.cloud.databricks.com/api/2.0/clusters/delete --data '{ "cluster_id": "1234-567890-frays123" }'`

Answer (score 0):

BLUF: You generally should create new clusters for scheduled workflows like those orchestrated from Airflow.

The `DatabrickSubmitRunOperator` uses the `jobs/runs/submit` endpoint:

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsSubmit

Under `tasks > existing_cluster_id` (emphasis mine):

> If existing_cluster_id, the ID of an existing cluster that is used for
> all runs of this task. When running tasks on an existing cluster, you
> may need to manually restart the cluster if it stops responding. *We
> suggest running jobs on new clusters for greater reliability*.

When you create a new cluster configured in the airflow operator, it creates a job cluster, which is terminated at the end of the job. Job clusters are much cheaper than all-purpose clusters, which persist indefinitely.

https://www.databricks.com/product/aws-pricing

1. Is there a way to have a cluster being callable by id even when it is down? **No, the submit job run will fail if the all-purpose cluster is terminated, or if you provide a job cluster id.**
2. Do people simply keep the clusters alive? **All-purpose clusters, which are created for analysis, collaboration, exploratory work, only terminate manually.**
3. Or am I completely wrong and starting clusters for each task won't generate more costs? **Job clusters cost <35% the cost of all-purpose clusters per DBU.**