# 'pimp' airflow databricks_hook or some python library to create and get the cluster_id for downstream tasks

Tags: python, airflow

I have similar questions like below, but i wonder there is an existing library work nicely with airflow to `create databricks cluster, return the cluster_id, and reuse for the downstream tasks`.

[Triggering Databricks job from Airflow without starting new cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561640/triggering-databricks-job-from-airflow-without-starting-new-cluster)

My study shows: the `DatabricksHook` class has quite some nice methods and api calls, but it does not have calls to `create cluster` and re-use the cluster in the same DAG.

if i have to add the methods myself:
In scala or other language, one could 'pimp' the library to add new methods to an 3rd party class. Any suggestion in `python` to do elegant way of adding extra methods?

- Do I have to either 'duplicate' some of the code which is written in the `Databrickshook` into my project, and add the missing methods
- or maybe contribute to the airflow project to 'add' the missing methods to the `DatabricksHook` class. This might take a longer time than i could wait for.

Info:

- the existing code for the hook class, where it has rest API calls: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/databricks_hook.html
- curl interface to create cluster etc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#--create

Answer (score 1):

Just a note Airflow 1.10 reached end-of-life on June 17 so you should switch to Airflow 2 as soon as possible as there will not be improvements nor even critical security fixes in 1.10.

In Airflow 2 you have Databricks provider and it has more methods (start_cluster/terminate_cluster). See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/_api/airflow/providers/databricks/hooks/databricks/index.html#airflow.providers.databricks.hooks.databricks.DatabricksHook.restart_cluster for example.

It seems it would be possible to use those methods. You can easily write your own Operator using those Hook methods and possibly you can contribute the operator back.

Comment: I see the provider in airflow 2.0 does not have the method I needed either. Just like what I posted in the question of 1.3, it has `restart_cluster` method. 
I end up creating my own method by using Adapter pattern using the existing hook. Will post the answer later. And considering to contribute back to the project too.

Comment: Great that you consider contributing it back !